# Meaning of command ls -lt | wc -l

Tags: linux, bash

My friend just passed me this command to count the number of files in a directory:

```
$ ls -lt | wc -l
```

Can someone please help me flush out the meaning of this command? I know that `ls` is to list all the files. But what does `-lt` mean?

Also, I get a different count if I use `ls | wc -l` with no `-lt` option. Why is that the case?

Comment: Incidentally, that command gives you one more than the number of files in the directory. (At least on my system. Maybe this varies by implementation of `ls`, I'm not sure.)

Comment: The total sum is specified by the man page, if that matters. I'm not sure whether the man pages are the same across all implementations.

Comment: The POSIX standard for [`ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) reflects historical practice and requires the 'total' line.  It would be astonishing to find a variant of `ls` that does not include it.

Comment: -1. Can't believe that you did not bother to check the man page before posting on SO.

Comment: I wished the `total xxxx` were printed on `stderr`...

Comment: Why -1 ? If someone has a genuine doubt and needs immediate help, SO is the best place for it. Please remove the -1

Comment: @slayedbylucifer He might not have known about man pages. That was the assumption I made anyway.

Comment: @anishsane The total isn't an error message, so stderr wouldn't be right.

Comment: @WillieWheeler: Can you please remove the -1. I think it is a genuine question

Comment: I didn't give it a -1. In fact I gave it a +1.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to get familiar with the "man (manual) pages":

```
$ man ls
```

In this case you'll see:

```
 -l      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  If
         the output is to a terminal, a total sum for all the file sizes is
         output on a line before the long listing.
 -t      Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before sorting the
         operands by lexicographical order.
```

Another way you can see the effect of the options is to run `ls` without piping to the `wc` command. Compare

```
$ ls
```

with

```
$ ls -l
```

and

```
$ ls -lt
```

Comment: But why is the output of ls | wc -l different from ls -lt | wc -l

Comment: Try the suggestions in the answer, you'll see why it's different.

Comment: Because the `-l` option shows the total number of files as one of the lines. E.g., "total 32".

Comment: And you get yet another answer with `ls -C | wc -l`, just for the record.